# What's the difference between つれて行く and 送りします

Tags: word-choice

つれて行く means to take someone somewhere, eg: 毋はびょういんへつれて行ってくれました
However in the classic ご覧のスポンサーの提供でお送りします,送りしますmeans like "bringing you, taking you." Are these two phrases interchangable?

Answer (score 2):

Think of it in terms of the English counterparts and it'll all make sense:

- 連れる to take someone/thing along with you, and do an action **together**.
- お送りする to take/send someone/thing to do something (nuance: you don't do the action).

Examples:

- 犬を連れて散歩する. To take a dog on a walk **with** you.
- お母さんを空港まで送った（お送りした）。 To take your mum to the airport.

So to go back to your question, the この番組は〜〜〜でお送りしました。They (the sponsors) brought you the TV program, but have nothing to do with it after "delivering" it.

Answer (score 1):

> 送りします

You don't say 「送りします」. It's お送りします(or お送りする in the plain form) or 送ります(or 送る in the plain form).  お送りします(お送りする) is the humble form of 送ります(送る).

> 母はびょういんへつれて行ってくれました

If you mean "My mom took me to the hospital", you could say:

> 母が/は(私を)[病院]{びょういん}まで/に送ってくれました。

送ってくれた would mean your mom took you to the hospital and left you there.

> or, 母が/は(私を)病院へ/に[連]{つ}れて行ってくれました。

連れて行ってくれた would mean your mom took you to the hospital and may or may not have accompanied you while you were there.

---

E.g.

> 母を病院に連れて行きました。

"I took my mom to the hospital (you may or may not have accompanied her)."

> 母を病院まで送りました*。

"I took my mom to the hospital (and left her there. You didn't accompany her)."
(*Use 送った/送りました, not お送りした/お送りしました; you don't use the humble form for the action you do for your own mother.)

---

> ご覧のスポンサーの提供でお送りします。

Literally, "We bring (this program) to you by the contributions of the sponsors that you see (here)." --> "This program is brought to you by these sponsors". You can't use 連れて行きます instead of お送りします here. You use 連れて行く for saying "to take/bring *someone* (normally, people or animal) somewhere".

Answer (score 0):

To keep it simple, 送る means to send something while 連れて行く means to take something or someone with you.
I would say that  連れて行く Involves another person while 送る doesn't do it by itself